# Dashing - uninitialized constant Nokogiri exception

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri, gemfile, rufus-scheduler

When I try to start dashing I receive the following error:

```
scheduler caught exception:
uninitialized constant Nokogiri
/Users/Adam/projects/ticker/jobs/sample.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

my Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'dashing'
```

my jobs folder consists of one folder, sample.rb:

```
SCHEDULER.every '2s' do
  oil_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.bloomberg.com/energy/"))
  a = oil_doc.css("table.std_table_module").first
  price = a.xpath("//td[3]").first.children.text
  send_event('valuation', { current: price })
end
```

I have tried adding  `require 'open-uri'` to the Gemfile and sample.rb but it has not helped!

Comment: `require 'nokogiri'` in your `sample.rb`?

Comment: yep that worked! I think i tried with `require 'Nokogiri'` before. Thanks for the help Dave!

Comment: Dave, could you please package your answer in an "answer" so that Adam can accept it and the question appears as "solved"? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is saying that it doesn't know anything about `Nokogiri`, which is a module defined in the nokogiri gem. In order to bring that into scope, you need to add:

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

to your `sample.rb` (usually at the top of the file).